# Best way to structure mysql database tables to have sequential IDs while unable to use auto_increment

Tags: php, mysql, database, layout, records

I have a problem trying to get my head around a database problem. The situation is as follows for a school enroling system.

Table 1 : School 
  CREATE TABLE school (schoolID auto_increment, school_name varchar, etc etc)

Table 2 : Students
  CREATE TABLE students (studentID auto_increment, student_name varchar, etc etc)

Table 3 : Enrolments (problem is here I believe)
  CREATE TABLE enrolments (enrolID, ...)

The issue is, previously the scope for the system was to allow enrolments to come from any number of locations, at any time, and would just insert into the database, which was fine, everything was autoincremented.

The scope changed, as they did not like the fact, that when reports would be done, when they retrieved the enrolments the numbers for the enrolments were scattered. They wanted each schools enrolment ID's to be sequential.

One thought I had was, option (a)

Create an enrolment table for *every school* (looking at around 1000-1500 total schools), this way every enrolment inserted, would be stored sequentially.

Option (B)

Have another table that would record the "lastrecord" inserted for that school.

CREATE TABLE lastrecord (schoolname varchar, nextrecord int)

With this, *before* every insert, it would have to check the database to find what the last ID used for that school was, retrieve the value, +1 to it, and then INSERT into the enrolment table.

using this method I would prefix the enrolment ID with the schools ID, for example
schoolID : 100

new enrolment ID : 10045
for their 45th student.

Then after every insert, update that table with the record used. This seems extremely inefficient but I am struggling to work out a better solution.

thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Why does somebody looking at the data care about the sequential ids? The ids should be irrelevant to everything but the database. Why don't you store enrollments as a pairing of SchoolId and StudentId and then group enrollments by SchoolId?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the autoincrement on two fields

Like:
`ADD PRIMARY KEY (`school_id`,`enrolID`)`
and set enrolID to autoincrement

Then each school will have its own autoincrement

Comment: this was what did it!! I just checked back here to upload my response, and i stumbled across another site talking about 'complex sequences' and they're explanation was exaclty as you mentioned above..

I wasted days thinking about this, thank you everyone for your input, finally it's working as I had envisaged..

The site I found help on -> http://www.codediesel.com/mysql/multi-column-sequences-in-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

A primary key in a database table has no real world meaning. Its just there to IDentify the row. 
So, you should split your student id (that has a meaning) and the primary key (that has no meaning) for the table into 2 fields.

The primary key is auto generated, for the generation of the student id you can use a algorithmic that has a meaning, for example year.number. Make a separate table that keeps track of what ID to give.